Consultion about a Recommendations system complexity as a graduation project
I'm doing a recommendation system as a graduation project with my two project partners we want to make a hybrid system that includes a content-based, collaborative and demographic recommendations module while utilizing reinforcement learning to keep up with new users data
as none of us has any experience we thought we would like to turn professional communities for advice
we started preprocessing on the data but have fears toward actually being able to implement everything before the deadline February 12th and if there's any integration limitation that we should know of before starting to train the modules so that we wouldn't have to start from scratch after we finish a module cause we should've done something differently if we were going for an hybrid system
so i want advice on how to go about this and can it all be achieved before the deadline cause if it's all too much we can downsize as our initial plan was a just a content-based recommendation system we want to know if our project is possible within our time constraints
edit: to make it clear as it looks like my earlier version wasn't adequate can the project described above be done by an inexperienced team in ML with a deadline of less than 2 months? and any resources to guide on how would be welcome

I was in the middle of writing an answer. I can understand why this question was closed, but I interpreted this as a question about development process to hit an aggressive deadline. I have voted to reopen the question.

Given that your downscaled idea seems to be a subset of your more ambitious project, it seems the obvious thing would be to focus on that and see how it goes;  Even the simplest projects can encounter unknowable and unforeseeable problems which eat up loads of time in unexpected ways.   On one hand, if you do get it done really quickly then you have it in the bag and can just pick another feature to build on-top. Otherwise if the smaller feature ends up turning out being a lot more complex than you'd anticipated, then by focusing just on that you are far more likely to get it done.

@GregBurghardt thanks and i apologize for the inadequate writing of my question as this is my first time using this site

@BenCottrell thanks for the insights will try to go in that direction after consulting with my partners

My answer was basically what @BenCottrell said in his comment. Start out small and simple. Get it working so you have something to turn in, and then iterate on that.
